# Trouble merging master to my feature branch using Intellij/Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My procedure:

1. In my feature branch I commit and push all my changes.
2. Using Intellij, I select origin/master -> merge into current.
3. The conflicting files are presented to me. I solve the conflicts in all files.

I get the following error:

> Couldn't check the working tree for unmerged files because of an
>   error. Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Although you may have resolved the conflicts in the files after the merge, Git does not actually know this.  Instead, it still sees the files in conflict.  To resolve this, you need to `git add` each file which was in conflict to mark it as resolved.

If you right click each file in conflict in IntelliJ, there should be a menu item for adding to version control.  You may also use the Project menu on the top to do this.

Once you have added each file, Git should report that all conflicts have been resolved, and you may commit the merge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why doesn't Intellij handle this automatically? Seems so straightforward...

Comment: @JoãoMatos IntelliJ doesn't really have much to do with this, it is how Git behaves.  If you do a merge from the command line, and get conflicts, you have to manually resolve them (which you did), _and_ you have to `git add` each file to mark it as resolved.  It would in general be undesirable for IntelliJ to automate this, because it can't always know what you want to do in this situation.

Comment: Please see my edit above. If I do "git merge master" instead and then using intellij I select "resolve conflicts" (step 3), I do not get the error. I did not need to use git add

Comment: I don't know what "resolve conflicts" is doing, but it must be IntelliJ's Git plugin trying to be smart or sensible.  What I described to you is how a Git merge is happening under the hood.  In general you should be prepared to resolved conflicts and mark those files as resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me. Git is still complaining with the same files after adding them as you instructed.

Comment: Run `git status` from the Git bash and see what it says.  Most likely, you still have one or more files which you did not resolve and/or `git add`.

Answer (score 1):

For my IntelliJ, if I resolve conflicts in it, it does add the files automatically. For your case, go to the console/terminal run `git status` to check if all files are green, if not do `git add .`